# Embed image as hidden digital watermark into another image?

Tags: hidden, watermark, steganography

How to melt an image as hidden water mark into another taget image, like the one described in wiki's Steganography page (The tree image encapsulates a cat image and can be revealed by applying some computations)? I find [another similar question here mentions about a project 'steghide'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113196/digital-watermarking-for-jpeg-png) but it can only use secret text as water mark. I'm looking for a secret image solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam".

Answer (score 2):

The following page, http://saisa.eu/blogs/Guidance/?p=1128,  mentions three tools, and at least one, OpenStego (https://sourceforge.net/projects/openstego/) pretends it can do your bidding.